# Filling Navigation properties in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there a way to fill the navigation properties of an object in Entity Framework along with loading the object itself by passing its primary key?

Lets say :

```
context.Request.LoadUsingPk(pk).LoadNavigationPropertiesRelatedToThisRequest
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - for eager loading, you add an `Include()` call ( [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) ):

```
context.Request.Include( request => request.NavigationProperty )...
```

It's an extension method, so you have to add a using to make it visible:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

---

There's an MSDN article all about it here: [`Entity Framework - Loading Related Entities`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)